# Database Design - Form Builder

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am developing an application with Spring MVC and hibernate where certain forms can be configured dynamically by admin.

For e.g. by default User will have attributes like firstname, lastname, email. But admin can add more fields like birthdate, address, anniversary.

For that I have decided to use form builder approach.

How do I design database for such system?

One approach I have decided is: http://goo.gl/sMVuWl

But here also it is not clear, how to store data for newly created fields.

Do let me know if you need more info.

I am using Spring MVC + hibernate and back end is MySQL

Comment: why do not use {index, key and value} approach? Most of time it works fine.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. I am not sure about index, key and value approach.

Comment: suppose your table `structure` is: {id(PK),iduser(INDX),key(VARCHAR),value(TEXT)}
Now lets insert some registers in your table `structure` as follow 
INSERT INTO `structure` VALUES (1,1, 'first_name', 'jhonson'),
INSERT INTO `structure` VALUES (2,1, 'last_name', 'harris'),
INSERT INTO `structure` VALUES (3,1, 'email', 'jhonson@domain.tld'), 
INSERT INTO `structure` VALUES (4,2, 'first_name', 'ozzy'), 
INSERT INTO `structure` VALUES (5,2, 'last_name', 'osbourne'), 
INSERT INTO `structure` VALUES (6,2, 'email', 'admin@domain.tld'), 
INSERT INTO `structure` VALUES (7,2, 'birthdate', '1945-01-01')

Comment: just a simple example, you can build your form with they key - value pair based on iduser(INDEX) to differentiate between user and admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams the solution [mentioned in the question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204097/dynamic-form-builder-forms-and-database-design) holds Form definition metadata. 
That structure will be used to render form for users.
Form fulfillment data will need other tables.

```
form-data:
---------
id PK
user-id FK
form-id FK
fulfillment-date
last-update-date
ETC...

form-element-data
-----------------
id PK
form-data-id FK
element-id FK
value (text)
ETC...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes... this design will help me to accommodate data